# button redirection base on geolocation

Tags: php, web, redirect, build, geolocation

how can I make one button to different URL base on my country location? (for instance, I visited a website if I'm in the USA and I click on a view button on that website I should be redirected to Amazon but if I'm in china and I click that same button I should be redirected to Alibaba). The language I want to use is PHP. I would really appreciate it if anyone can assist me with this request. Thank you

Comment: You need to do the research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Currently, this question is too broad.

Comment: you can use google services, it permits to know where the machine is and location. you can read the page https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?hl=es&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_432573225308-ADGP_Hybrid+%7C+AW+SEM+%7C+BKWS+~+Google+Maps+API+BMM-KWID_43700053361875350-aud-905774763988:kwd-299558369886-userloc_1003659&utm_term=KW_%2Bapi%20%2Bgoogle%20%2Bmap-ST_%2Bapi+%2Bgoogle+%2Bmap&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxPvMkoe36gIVXwiICR2UyAK5EAAYASAAEgLazPD_BwE